# Inconsistent return values from Google Maps geometry calculations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an application using Google Maps. I have some logic which expects very consistent output form the `google.maps.geometry.spherical` library.

Basically I am trying to draw a box with precise dimensions.

My sample code looks like this:

```
function (LatLng) {

  var NW, NE, SW, SE, length, dist; 

  // LatLng is a coordinate
  NW = LatLng

  // I have a length variable
  length = 25

  // Using the single reference point as NorthWest corner of the box, 
  // I calculate the remaining 3 corners
  NE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(LatLng, length, 90);
  SW = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(LatLng, length, 180);
  SE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(SW, length, 90);

  // now I check the dimensions
  dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(NE, NW);

  console.log('NW/NE bounds distance', dist);
}
```

I am expecting to get a value of 25 (equal to `length`), and indeed my subsequent logic depends on `dist >= length`. However, when I run this multiple times I get some degree of variability around 25. I find anything from range `22.499999999193243` to `22.50000000221681` for example.

Is this variability to be expected? Is this a feature of the developer API?

If so, does anyone have suggestions on how to account for this in my code, as simply adding `0.000000001` to the dimensions seems a bit fudgey to me.

---

P.S.

This is a simplified version of my problem. In the real code I am actually generating a `Rectangle` object, then calculating the distances between corners to compare to `length`. However the principal, and error, is exactly the same.

Comment: Where do you get NW from?  Is that "LatLng"?

Comment: Those [differences are insignificant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), maybe you should change your code that is sensitive to that difference.

Comment: Oops. Yes. NW is LatLng. Edited Question.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the difference is minute, especially by GIS terms. I was more looking for clarification on why the returned values vary given the same inputs.

Comment: I assume your results were 2.499999999193243 to 2.50000000221681.The difference from 25 occur because the lines of longitude converge to the poles and this is taken into consideration in the spherical library.